# How to activate Jcrop selection after ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, jcrop

I am using Jcrop on my project. The problem is not critical but would be better if I can fix it.

I can upload an image via ajax request (not Jquery ajax) and image could load to page after upload without page refresh. Until now, everything works great. After image loaded into page, Jrop doesn't become active without refreshing page. Here is Jcrop activator script:

```
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
      jQuery('#cropbox').Jcrop({
        onChange: showPreview,
        onSelect: showPreview,
        aspectRatio: 3/4
      });
    });
```

I am not sure is it important, this script is not inside $(document).ready(function(){}.

I tried triggering Jcrop with $('#cropbox').load and $('#cropbox').click functions instead of jQuery(window).load(function(){} function but nothing happened.

Do you have any idea? Is that possible to activate Jcrop just after loading image into page via ajax request without refreshing browser?

Here is Jcrop usage:

```
// Remember to invoke within jQuery(window).load(...)
// If you don't, Jcrop may not initialize properly
$(window).load(function(){
                var imgWidth = $('#cropbox').width();
                var imgHeight = $('#cropbox').height();

                $('#cropbox').Jcrop({

                    onChange: showPreview,
                    onSelect: showPreview,
                    aspectRatio: 3/4,
                    setSelect: [ ((imgWidth/2)-60), 60, ((imgWidth/2)+60), 220 ],
                    addClass: 'custom',
                    bgColor: 'yellow',
                    bgOpacity: .8,
                    sideHandles: false

                });

            });
```

And image upload button:

```
<button onclick="ajaxUpload(this.form,'http://www.yemeklog.com/ajax/ajaxupload.php?filename=filename&amp;maxSize=9999999999&amp;maxW=400&amp;fullPath=http://www.yemeklog.com/images/users/160/&amp;relPath=../images/users/160/&amp;colorR=120&amp;colorG=120&amp;colorB=120&amp;maxH=600','upload_area','&lt;img src=\'http://static.yemeklog.com/images/ajax-bar-loader.gif\' width=\'220\' height=\'19\' border=\'0\' /&gt;','&lt;img src=\'images/error.gif\' width=\'16\' height=\'16\' border=\'0\' /&gt; An error occured. Please contact.'); return false;">Upload Image</button>
```

And ajaxupload.js file:

```
function $m(theVar){
    return document.getElementById(theVar)
}
function remove(theVar){
    var theParent = theVar.parentNode;
    theParent.removeChild(theVar);
}
function addEvent(obj, evType, fn){
    if(obj.addEventListener)
        obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, true)
    if(obj.attachEvent)
        obj.attachEvent("on"+evType, fn)
}
function removeEvent(obj, type, fn){
    if(obj.detachEvent){
        obj.detachEvent('on'+type, fn);
    }else{
        obj.removeEventListener(type, fn, false);
    }
}
function isWebKit(){
    return RegExp(" AppleWebKit/").test(navigator.userAgent);
}
function ajaxUpload(form,url_action,id_element,html_show_loading,html_error_http){
    var detectWebKit = isWebKit();
    form = typeof(form)=="string"?$m(form):form;
    var erro="";
    if(form==null || typeof(form)=="undefined"){
        erro += "Hata kodu: 1.\n";
    }else if(form.nodeName.toLowerCase()!="form"){
        erro += "Hata kodu: 2.\n";
    }
    if($m(id_element)==null){
        erro += "Hata kodu: 3.\n";
    }
    if(erro.length>0){
        alert("Yükleme esnasında hata oluştu:\n" + erro);
        return;
    }
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("id","ajax-temp");
    iframe.setAttribute("name","ajax-temp");
    iframe.setAttribute("width","0");
    iframe.setAttribute("height","0");
    iframe.setAttribute("border","0");
    iframe.setAttribute("style","width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");
    form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
    window.frames['ajax-temp'].name="ajax-temp";
    var doUpload = function(){
        removeEvent($m('ajax-temp'),"load", doUpload);
        var cross = "javascript: ";
        cross += "window.parent.$m('"+id_element+"').innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML; void(0);";
        $m(id_element).innerHTML = html_error_http;
        $m('ajax-temp').src = cross;
        if(detectWebKit){
            remove($m('ajax-temp'));
        }else{
            setTimeout(function(){ remove($m('ajax-temp'))}, 250);
        }
        $('#ajax_image_container').slideDown('slow');
    }
    addEvent($m('ajax-temp'),"load", doUpload);
    form.setAttribute("target","ajax-temp");
    form.setAttribute("action",url_action);
    form.setAttribute("method","post");
    form.setAttribute("enctype","multipart/form-data");
    form.setAttribute("encoding","multipart/form-data");
    if(html_show_loading.length > 0){
        $m(id_element).innerHTML = html_show_loading;
    }
    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call jcrop on the image after getting the ajax request back.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    var $myImage = $("<img></img>", {
        src: data.img,    
      }).appendTo('#cropbox');
    $myImage.Jcrop({
      onChange: showPreview,
      onSelect: showPreview,
      aspectRatio: 3/4
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for help but I didn't get what you say. Should I replace this with my script or what? My ajax request is **not a Jquery ajax** request. What url should I use?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself more. No, you don't need to use my script. I just wanted to show a possible way of doing it. What I think you should do is call jcrop on the image after you load it on the page. The script you have in your question doesn't work because the window load event has already passed when the page loads in the browser. Cheers!

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for reply. I am still solutionless :) I think I should try to convert ajax scripts into Jquery ajax if I could. I hope I could...

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your ajax script for this? You should be able to execute jcrop after the code to put the image into `#cropbox`.

Comment: thanks for interest. I just edited post with all used scripts. I tried initializing Jcrop inside ajaxupload.js but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Where did you initialize it? I could be misunderstanding your code, but I think it should go in the last or second to last line in doUpload().

Comment: I added it end of doUpload() but not working. $('#ajax_image_container').slideDown('slow'); which is also on last line works properly. I think problem is deeper and I am not fighting for it anymore. Thank you.